# Specify Namespaces when using XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to take an output from xml document using c#. But I don't receive any output to the grid and no error messages are generated. I assume this should be a mistake that i'm doing when using XmlnamespaceManager. I will show the coding that I'm using. Can somebody please help me to identify where am I going wrong. I have attached a sample xml file herewith. Thanks in advance[image]

```
public void InitializePatchListArray()
{
    ArrayPatchList[0, 0] = "Installed Patch";
    ArrayPatchList[0, 1] = "/compositeReport/eisRecommendedPatchReport/@xmlns:ns2/ns2:recommendedPatchList/ns2:recommendedPatch/ns2:installedPatchId";
}

public void PopulatePatchList()
{
    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDoc.Load(XMLFileLocation);

    for (int i = 0; i <6; i++)
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://webhome.central/xml/ns/bre/RuleService");
        XmlNodeList XmlValueList = XmlDoc.SelectNodes(ArrayPatchList[i, 1].ToString(),manager);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't have the `/@xmlns:ns2` section in your path expression? I'm not clear on what you were trying to do with that portion.

Comment: why are you creating the namespace manager inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it is just your xpath - the odd `@xmlns:ns2` looks out of place.

```
public void InitializePatchListArray()
{
  ArrayPatchList[0, 0] = "Installed Patch";
  ArrayPatchList[0, 1] = "/compositeReport/eisRecommendedPatchReport/ns2:recommendedPatchList/ns2:recommendedPatch/ns2:installedPatchId";
}
```

should work fine.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I think that using **serialization** may be more elegant and clear. Moreover, if you're using Visual Studio 2012, you can create a class from XML automatically and then, where serializing or deserializing, point the namespaces in a simple way